# Ambiguous use of 'value'

Tags: swift, swift3

After converting my project to Swift 3, I'm getting this message:

> Ambiguous use of 'value'

On the line

```
let fetcher = wrapper?.value as? Fetcher<UIImage>
```

I'm trying to associate with NSObject instances using extensions

```
public extension UIImageView {
   var hnk_fetcher : Fetcher<UIImage>! {
      get {
          let wrapper = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &HanekeGlobals.UIKit.SetImageFetcherKey) as? ObjectWrapper
          let fetcher = wrapper?.value as? Fetcher<UIImage>  //Ambiguous use of 'value'
          return fetcher
      }
      set (fetcher) {
          var wrapper : ObjectWrapper?
          if let fetcher = fetcher {
              wrapper = ObjectWrapper(value: fetcher)
          }
          objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &HanekeGlobals.UIKit.SetImageFetcherKey, wrapper, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
      }
  }
```

Here is my ObjectWrapper class.

```
class ObjectWrapper : NSObject {
    let value: Any

    init(value: Any) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Everything was fine before migrating the code. What went wrong?

Comment: Do optionals have a `value` member? It may not be able to figure out if you want the member of the optional, or the member of the object the optional is wrapping.

Comment: @Carcigenicate There is no `value` member

Comment: @Hamish Great! Just renaming the `value` property fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Ana No problem – I figured I might as well move the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the use of `.value` is ambiguous to Swift, as it could either refer to your `value` property, or to any of `NSObject`'s [`value(for...)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value) family of methods for Key-Value Coding.

I don't *believe* there's an easy way of disambiguating this by just using Swift syntax (given that your `value` property is typed as `Any` – which the methods can also be typed as).

Although amusingly, you can actually use Key-Value Coding *itself* to get the value:

```
let fetcher = wrapper?.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(ObjectWrapper.value)) as? Fetcher<UIImage>
```

But honestly, the easiest solution would be just to rename your `value` property to something else (`base` maybe?).

Comment: Although if it really bothers you, you can always [file a bug report/improvement](https://bugs.swift.org) complaining that there's no easy way to disambiguate this by just using Swift syntax (there really should be *some* way to do it).